# Fill DataGridview with empty rows in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to fill my point of sales application datagridview fill with empty rows when load. how can I do that using c# .net or can do it with database rows. can anyone help me.

I tried this code:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count < 20){
    int r = 20 - dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){
        AddARow(dt);
    }
}
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.SkyBlue;
dataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
```

I use Mysql database for my application. I saw many point of sales systems using this empty rows in this interface.

[this is the gridview i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ55B.jpg)

Comment: What is `dt` and where is it defined? Sounds like you just want `dataGridView1.Rows.Add();` instead of `AddARow(dt);` - Is this data bound?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to add empty elements as ItemSource:

```
    public class DataItem
    {
        public string Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Column2 { get; set; }

    }


    private void populategrid()
    {
        ObservableCollection<DataItem> list = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        list.Add(new DataItem { Column1 = "", Column2 = "" });
        list.Add(new DataItem { Column1 = "", Column2 = "" });
        list.Add(new DataItem { Column1 = "", Column2 = "" });
        list.Add(new DataItem { Column1 = "", Column2 = "" });

        myDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

In this case a used a list of DataItem that has strings as properties, but you can use any type.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a row to your DataGridView is the "dataGridView1.Rows.Add()" method. 
Use it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
}
```

Or like this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(20);
```

Note that you have to add columns first for this to work, otherwise you will get an InvalidOperationException